# Is there any way to handle a defined exception globally in a PLSQL package

Tags: exception, plsql

I'm writing a PLSQL package with several procedures, any one of which can generate an exception I've defined, and I've got that exception handled in each procedure. Thus;

```
package BODY pkg 
  PROCEDURE first
  BEGIN
  .....
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN foobar ...
  END first;

  PROCEDURE second
  BEGIN
  .....
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN foobar ...
  END second;
END pkg;
```

And it works.

However, is there any way to define an exception handler which will deal with "foobar" when it's raised in ANY procedure inside the package so each procedure doesn't need an exception section just to deal with the foobar condition? The actual code has about a dozen procedures.

Comment: No, unless you add another "hub" procedure acting as a receiving layer on top of each procedure call.

Comment: I was hoping, but that's more work than worth. Thank you, Sebas.

Comment: It might be allright to just do what you're doing anyway. What's the real world scenario?

Comment: I don't think there is such thing. Maybe you can encapsulate the piece of logic that raises that exception in a single procedure and always call that procedure from the other ones...

Answer (score 1):

I would move the common code to a single routine, e.g.:

```
  package BODY pkg 

  PROCEDURE foobar_handler IS
  BEGIN
  .....
  END foobar_handler;

  PROCEDURE first
  BEGIN
  .....
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN foobar THEN foobar_handler;
  END first;

  PROCEDURE second
  BEGIN
  .....
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN foobar THEN foobar_handler;
  END second;
END pkg;
```